# SharePoint OOTB Approval Workflow Issue

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I'm getting a strange issue when setting up a SharePoint Approval workflow. This is in MOSS 2007 running on Win 2008.

If I try and create a new approval workflow(or any ootb workflow), I will get to the Add a workflow page (_layouts/AddWrkfl.aspx) and enter the initial paramaters. Once I click next to go to the Customize Workflow (_layouts/CstWrkflIP.aspx) I get the following error in the main section of the page:

There has been an error while loading the form. A required resource could not be downloaded. To try to resume the download, refresh the page.

This has me stumped. I find no error in the event log or SharePoint logs.
I saw a previous post point to a HTTPModule causing the error. The only extra HTTPModule we use is for DevExpress. I removed it, but still had the some issue.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

I've just noticed that the issue does not occur in Google Chrome, this lets me get to the Customize Workflow page with no issue. It's obviously some IE issue but still dont understand what. I've asked colleagues to try and they get the same issue in IE.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get around the issue by going into IE - Tools -Internet Options-  Advanced - Reset.

I would love to know what IE was not happy about though...